# XML Data Binding in .NET - Getting node value where attribute value is equal to something

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, data-binding, ascx

I'm developing a .NET control which needs to list values from an XML file based on an attribute value in a node and I'm having difficulty getting to my data.

The XML is formatted like this:

```
<root>
  <item>
     <field name="business title">My Hardware Store</field>
     <field name="address">123 Main Street</field>
  </item>
  <item>
     <field name="business title">Corner Bar</field>
     <field name="address">345 Country Blvd</field>
  </item>
</root>
```

I've got the XML file properly loading using the following VB:

```
 Dim doc As New XmlDocument()

doc.Load(MapPath(filepath))
Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("root/item/field")

lvDirectoryListing.DataSource = nodes
'binding dataset to listview.
lvDirectoryListing.DataBind()
```

But I"m having trouble figuring out the binding in the ASCX file. I need the repeater to display all of the business titles on the page. So, I need the node value when the node name is "field" and the name attribute value is "business title". I can find all kinds of information on how to get a node value and how to get an attribute value, but nothing for what I'm looking for. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just change your xpath to:

```
doc.SelectNodes("root/item/field[name='business title']")
```

Comment: That looks reasonable, but then what would I put into the ASCX file to display it? <%# Bind("field")%>?

Comment: Not sure. Wouldn't it be `Bind("Value")`? This is why some people prefer to use MVVM and bind to a ViewModel rather than directly to an xml document.

Comment: That didn't display anything. I've moved on to seeing if I can use a conditional in my data binder to do the trick. I will need my datasource to hold the rest of the data for later operations anyway, so filtering it at this point in the code isn't really going to help. Thanks for the answer, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Got this one figured out. In the VB code, I need only pull down the first two nodes:

```
Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("root/item")
```

Then, in the ASCX file, use XPath in the databinding to limit results to the node value of the field with this particular attribute:

```
<%# XPath("feild[@name='business title']")%>
```